# Is this the most efficient way to search for a substring?

Tags: c#, performance

I'm working with some code that returns a code to indicate the type of user that they are (e.g. "A", "B", "C", "D", etc.).  Each code corresponds to a specific role and/or scope (e.g. across the entire application or just for the object being worked on).

In some code that I'm looking at, I see calls to check if the user's code is one of several in order to allow them to perform some action.  So I see calls like:

```
//"B" would come from the database
string userCode = "B";

//some more work...

//if the user's code is either A or C...
if("AC".IndexOf(userCode) >= 0) {
  //do work that allows the user to progress
} else {
  //notify user they can't do this operation
}
```

Is this an efficient way of performing this check?  Are there more efficient ways?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the de-compiled code for `Contains()`, it just calls `IndexOf()` with `StringComparison.Ordinal`, so I'd say `IndexOf()` is most efficient (by a very small hair) i if used in the same way (Ordinal) since it has one less method call, but `Contains()` is more readable and therefore more maintainable...

```
public bool Contains(string value)
{
    return (this.IndexOf(value, StringComparison.Ordinal) >= 0);
}
```

As in all things, I'd go with what's more readable and maintainable then splitting hairs on performance.  Only do micro-optimization when you know there's a bottleneck at this point.

**UPDATE**: Over 1,000,000 iterations:

- Contains(value) - took 130ms
- IndexOf(value, StringComparison.Ordinal) - took 128 ms

So as you can see, very, very NEAR same.  Once again, go with what's more maintainable.

**UPDATE 2**: If your code is always a single char (not a 1-char string), IndexOf() is faster:

- Contains(char value) - took 94 ms
- IndexOf(char value) - took 16 ms

If you know your char codes are always a single char, it is about an order of magnitude faster to use `IndexOf()` with a char argument.

This is because `Contains(char value)` is an extension method off of `IEnumerable<T>` and not a first class method of `string`.

*But* once again ~100 ms over 1,000,000 iterations is really, truly, quite negligible.

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking for a single character, and it is not case-sensitive, use the overload that works with a char. Searching for a single case-insensitive char is quicker than a sub-string.

```
"AC".IndexOf('C');
```

This would have to be *ridiculously* performance critical to matter though. What you are doing would be extremely fast with any obvious method.

**Update - Timings**

```
[Test]
public void Time()
{
    const string UserCode = "C";
    const char UserCodeChar = 'C';
    const int Iterations = 10000000;

    double adjust = 0;

    Func<Action, double> time = action =>
    {
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < Iterations; i++) action();
        return sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
    };

    Action<string, Action> test = (desc, t) =>
    {
        double ms = time(t) - adjust;
        Console.WriteLine(desc + " time: {0}ms", ms);
    };

    adjust = time(() => { });

    test("IndexOfString", () => "AC".IndexOf(UserCode));
    test("IndexOfString", () => "AC".IndexOf(UserCode));

    test("ContainsString", () => "AC".Contains(UserCode));
    test("ContainsString", () => "AC".Contains(UserCode));

    test("IndexOfChar", () => "AC".IndexOf(UserCodeChar));
    test("IndexOfChar", () => "AC".IndexOf(UserCodeChar));
}
```

Result:

> IndexOfString time: 1035.2984ms
>   IndexOfString time: 1026.2889ms
>   ContainsString time: 764.9274ms
>   ContainsString time: 736.7621ms
>   IndexOfChar time: 92.9008ms
>   IndexOfChar time: 92.9961ms

Answer (score 3):

I think you can assume that system libraries are implemented quite efficient and that you are usually not able to speed up things using home made solutions. That said, I think your way of encoding user types is quite strange. Why not use Bitmasks or something like that? Beside that, I would assume that your question is irrelevant at all: CompareD to accessing a database and doing "some work" your check does not matter at all.

Comment: I agree with this answer completely.  It's hard to imagine that performance is important here, but if it is, bitmasks would be a far, far better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Contains() function is one option. I don't know how it performs versus index of, but it's an option:

```
string userCode = "B";
string someStringToSearchIn = "Current user is: B";

if (someStringToSearchIn.Contains(userCode))
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: This is backwards. The `userCode` is a single letter, so you need a `Contains()` call for each possible type ("A", "B", etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'm not really sure why you're concerned about efficiency here. You are performing an *extremely* short string search, which is unlikely to bog down performance.

That being said, I actually find the style confusing. If you want to know if `userCode` is one of "A" and "C", just say so:

```
if (userCode.Equals("A") || userCode.Equals("C"))
{
    // Do something useful
}
```

Crystal clear, and most likely performant as well.

As a side note, if you can get these codes into an `enum` instead, things could be much easier:

```
[Flags]
public enum UserCode
{
    None = 0,
    A = 1,
    B = 2,
    C = 4
}
```

Now you can just say:

```
if ((userCode & (UserCode.A | UserCode.C)) != UserCode.None)
{
    // Do something even more useful
}
```

Comment: Your implementation of the `UserCode` enum is weird.  The point of a bitmask enum of flags is so that you don't have to define `AC`, `BC`, `ABC`, et al.  Why would you do it that way?

Answer (score -1):

At least on my computer, `Contains` with a `string` (rather than a `char`) is fastest.

Results:
IndexOf time: 616ms
Contains time: 499ms
Contains char time: 707ms

Code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string userCode = "B";
        char userCodeChar = 'B';
        int iterations = 10000000;
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            if ("AC".IndexOf(userCode) >= 0)
            {
                int a = 1 + 1;
            }
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("IndexOf time: {0}ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);


        sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            if ("AC".Contains(userCode))
            {
                int a = 1 + 1;
            }
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Contains time: {0}ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);



        sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            if ("AC".Contains(userCodeChar))
            {
                int a = 1 + 1;
            }
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Contains char time: {0}ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        Console.WriteLine("Done");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Try: IndexOf(value, StringComparison.Ordinal), i think you'll find it faster than Contains since Contains calls it.

Comment: @chibacity maybe it's new in .NET 4.0?  It definitely compiles and runs.  I don't know if that's the reason for the downvote (or if it was you), but if it is, I'd appreciate it being removed.

Comment: Ah, I see, it's treating the string as an `IEnumerable<char>` and it's just the extension method on `IEnumerable<T>`